# How do I highlight a column from the top to the nth row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to highlight columns and rows in a table from the top to the selected cell and from the left to the selected cell.

What I have so far is that both the whole column and whole row is highlighted.

The desired outcome would be like this:

[image]

I did a search on the internet but could not find a similar case.

```js
$(document).on('click', "td", function(event) {

  var table = 'table'
  var styleA = {
    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)',
    '-moz-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)',
    'box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)'
  };
  var styleB = {
    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    '-moz-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    'box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    'outline': ' 3px solid #086aa7'
  };

  $(table).find("td,tr").removeAttr('style');
  $(table).find("td").removeAttr('style'); 
  //$(this).parent('tr').css(styleA);
  $(this).parent('tr').find('td').css(styleA);
  $('td:eq(' + this.cellIndex + ')', 'tr').css(styleA); 
  $(this).css(styleB);
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("table");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $("table").find("tr,td").removeAttr('style');
    $("table").find("td").removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

table td[contentEditable=true] {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(186, 210, 225, 0.51);
  outline: 3px solid #086AA7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `prevAll` function to select all previous siblings. Try the following:

```js
$(document).on('click', "td", function(event) {

  var table = 'table'
  var styleA = {
    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)',
    '-moz-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)',
    'box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)'
  };
  var styleB = {
    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    '-moz-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    'box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    'outline': ' 3px solid #086aa7'
  };

  $(table).find("td,tr").removeAttr('style');
  $(this).prevAll().css(styleA);
  $(this).parent().prevAll().find('td:eq(' + this.cellIndex + ')', 'tr').css(styleA); 
  $(this).css(styleB);
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("table");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $("table").find("tr,td").removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

table td[contentEditable=true] {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(186, 210, 225, 0.51);
  outline: 3px solid #086AA7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', "td", function(event) {
  var table = 'table'
  var styleA = {
    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)',
    '-moz-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)',
    'box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(213, 228, 237, 1)'
  } ;
  var styleB = {
    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    '-moz-box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)',
    'box-shadow': 'inset 10px 10px 0px 200px rgba(220, 231, 237, 1)'
  } ;

  $(table).find("td, tr").removeAttr('style') ;
  $(table).find("td").removeAttr('style') ;


  var i = 0 ; /* Position of <td> in <tr> */

  /* Fill all <td> in the same <tr> */
  var tdElem = $(this) ;
  while($(tdElem).length > 0) {
    $(tdElem).css(styleA) ;

    tdElem = $(tdElem).prev("td") ;
    i++ ;
  }

  /* Fill all <td> in prev <tr> */
  var trElem = $(this).parent("tr").prev() ;
  while($(trElem).length > 0) {
    $(trElem).find("td:nth-child(" + i + ")").css(styleB) ;

    trElem = $(trElem).prev("tr") ;
  }
}) ;

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("table");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $("table").find("tr,td").removeAttr('style');
    $("table").find("td").removeAttr('style');
  }
}) ;
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

table td[contentEditable=true] {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(186, 210, 225, 0.51);
  outline: 3px solid #086AA7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```